# "Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing in CORS" when it appears in the console

Tags: javascript, nginx, cors, fetch

I'm getting a "Cross-origin request blocked. Reason: Access-Control-allow-Origin missing in cors header" when it's visible in the console. What is causing this issue and how to resolve it?

The nginx server is set up as a proxy pass and the requests are made using `lvh.me` instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

code used to make the request :

```js
fetch(
  'url.to/fetch',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': auth
  }),
  body: JSON.stringify(body)
})
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
  return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
  console.log('success', data);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('failed', error);
});
```

OPTIONS response headers:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
    Date: Mon, 12 Apr 2021 13:44:53 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 12
    Connection: keep-alive
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
```

OPTIONS request headers:

```
Accept
    */*
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language
    fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Access-Control-Request-Headers
    authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method
    POST
Cache-Control
    no-cache
Connection
    keep-alive
DNT
    1
Host
    pubsub.warths.fr
Origin
    http://127.0.0.1:8080
Pragma
    no-cache
Referer
    http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Sec-GPC
    1
User-Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0
```

nginx config:

```
server {
    server_name my.domain.name;

    location / {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS';


        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

---

Note: using `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';` didn't fix the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my http://localhost CORS origin not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/why-does-my-http-localhost-cors-origin-not-work)

Comment: The OPTIONS request is a preflight request, it should be followed up by the real request. Does the header appear on the response to the POST request too? Is the POST request made at all?

Comment: [How do I add Access-Control-Allow-Origin in NGINX?](https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx)

Comment: I tried to load the page using "lvh.me" instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1, but the result was the same, so I don't think id comes from here.

Comment: the post request is made, but it's flagged with "CORS Missing Allow Origin" in the console but the server receives the authorization header and responds with a 401. The post response doesn't contain any "Access-Control-*" headers.

Answer (score -1):

I played a bit with the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers, and when I added the `Content-Type` header to the list the error disappeared. I don't know all the ramifications of it but it looks like the request was refused because it used the `Content-Type` header but it wasn't allowed by default.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments the `Content-Type` header is not considered "simple" if it's not one of the following : `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain`.
I was using `application/json` so the request was rejected. Adding `Content-Type` to the allowed headers enables the use of nonsimple values and thus fixed the issue.

So I change :

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization';
```

to

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type';
```

Comment: This is because `Content-Type` is a non-simple request header (and there must be permitted) unless it has one of three specific values, which does not include `application/json`; see "Non-simple requests" under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work/10636765#10636765 However, I'm unsure why the client didn't include it in the OPTIONS request. Regardless, it looks like authorizing it in the response works!

Answer (score -1):

It can be fixed by :-

Remove this part from nginx configuration :-

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
```

And instead of above statement write

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' <front_end_host_address>;
```

suppose if your are running your front-end on `http://localhost:3000`, then add

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:3000' always;
```